# Necesito que la variable xCuenta no se reinicie a 0, por ej al rotar la pantalla

Tags: android-studio, variables

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        // defino variables de botones y texto
        ImageButton imgButtonUp;
        ImageButton imgButtonDw;
        ImageButton imgButtonRes;
        ImageButton imgButtonInfo;
        ToggleButton toogleB;
        TextView textCount;
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
        int xCuenta=0;

         @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // defs
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // Defino variables
            textCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTurno);
            imgButtonUp = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibuUp);
            imgButtonDw = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibuDw);
            imgButtonRes = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibuRes);
            imgButtonInfo =(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibuInfo);
            toogleB = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tgSound );

    // Defino Sonido ding dong
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ding2);

            // onclick del boton Up
            imgButtonUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
    // incremento cuenta
                    xCuenta++;
                    if (xCuenta > 99) {
                        xCuenta = 0;
                    }
    // convierto y presento
                    textCount.setText(String.format(Locale.US,"%02d", xCuenta));

    // Reprocir sound
                    mediaPlayer.start();

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Por defecto, cuando la pantalla se rota, es decir, la aplicación pasa de modo `portrait` a `landscape` o al revés, la Actividad se mata y se recrea. Para asegurarte de que no se pierde información, por ejemplo el caso de que se te resetee la variable *xCuenta*, tienes que guardar y reestablecer los datos utilizando los métodos del ciclo de vida.

Tienes más información en [developer.android.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#SavingPersistentState)

Te pongo un pequeño código de ejemplo de esa web y te hago una explicación rápida.

```
public class CalendarActivity extends Activity {
    ...
    static final int DAY_VIEW_MODE = 0;
    static final int WEEK_VIEW_MODE = 1;

    private SharedPreferences mPrefs;
    private int mCurViewMode;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //2
        SharedPreferences mPrefs = getSharedPreferences();
        mCurViewMode = mPrefs.getInt("view_mode", DAY_VIEW_MODE);
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        //1
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = mPrefs.edit();
        ed.putInt("view_mode", mCurViewMode);
        ed.commit();
    }
}
```

En 1: El método *onPause* es llamado antes de rotar la pantalla, aprovechamos ese momento para almacenar cualquier variable que necesitemos, en tu caso sería *xCuenta*.

En 2: Si al crear la *Activity* tenemos un valor almacenado, lo obtenemos y lo seteamos.

Esta pregunta [fue respondida en el foro ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123407/losing-data-when-rotate-screen), la he traducido y adaptado:

Comment: tuve que agregar esta linea porque me daba error <br/> `public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";` <br/>` // si hay valor almacenado, lo tomo
                SharedPreferences mPrefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0 );` y ahora no puedo refrescar el textview correspondiente, me pone el valor default y si lo modifica bien cuando lo utilizo en los buttons correspondientes.

Comment: Creo que es mejor la parte donde se usan los métodos onSaveInstanceState y onRestoreInstanceState en la misma pregunta pero en la respuesta: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10748126/323149. También decir que se puede usar el estado guardado en el onCreate pero para guardarlo hay que tener sobreescribir el onSaveInstanceState